# Changing text for a hidden Ext JS SplitButton

Tags: javascript, extjs, split-button

When I change the text of a hidden Ext JS SplitButton, the button is not sized correctly when the panel containing the button is made visible.

The button sits in a panel.  The panel and other panels are shown and hidden using a card layout.  I am using Ext JS 3.3.1.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing `panel.doLayout(false, true);` right after you change the button text.